# How to customize column names in vb using array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, datagridview

I am new to vb.net. I have a sample datagridview with some sample codes from the internet in it. The running codes is using array and basing on the codes:

```
Const NumberOfColumns As Integer = 8
        Const NumberOfRows As Integer = 8

        Dim ColumnNumber As Integer
        Dim RowNumber As Integer

        Dim A As Integer = Asc("Pupil's Name")

        Dim Array2D(NumberOfRows, NumberOfColumns) As Integer

        DataGridView1.ColumnCount = NumberOfColumns
        DataGridView1.RowCount = NumberOfRows

        'Make the headers

        For RowNumber = 0 To NumberOfRows - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows.Item(RowNumber).HeaderCell.Value = _
  (RowNumber + 1).ToString
        Next

        For ColumnNumber = 0 To NumberOfColumns - 1
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(ColumnNumber).HeaderCell.Value = _
   Chr(A + ColumnNumber).ToString
            DataGridView1.Columns.Item(ColumnNumber).HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = _
   DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        Next

        'Fill the Array

        For RowNumber = 0 To NumberOfRows - 1
            For ColumnNumber = 0 To NumberOfColumns - 1
                Array2D(RowNumber, ColumnNumber) = _
   RowNumber * NumberOfColumns + ColumnNumber
            Next
        Next

        'Fill the Data Grid

        For RowNumber = 0 To NumberOfRows - 1
            For ColumnNumber = 0 To NumberOfColumns - 1
                DataGridView1.Item(ColumnNumber, RowNumber).Value = _
   Array2D(RowNumber, ColumnNumber)
                DataGridView1.Item(ColumnNumber, RowNumber).Style.Alignment = _
   DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            Next
        Next
```

i do not know how to insert my customized column name. I tried right-clicking on the datagridview and edit its column name but when i run it, the column names are getting the first letter of my edited column name on the datagridview and looped it. sorry if there is a duplication about my question. I just posted the codes so that I can let anyone understand what I am trying to ask. I really need help with this. :(

Comment: I tried your code and the only thing a bit odd is the column's header that starts with the letter 'P' instead of 'A'. But what is your expected output for the column's headers?

Comment: I want to name it with Pupil's Name, Quiz Average, Quiz Percentage, Recitation Average, Recitation Percentage etc..

Comment: The answer below is okay but what i meant is to insert that in the codes above. It's okay for the one who answered at least there is another option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns.aspx.

Here is a how you do it.

' Set the column header names.

```
dataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "Recipe"
dataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Category"
dataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "Main Ingredients"
dataGridView1.Columns(3).Name = "Rating"
```

Comment: Thanks. But what i meant is to insert that in my array code above.

Comment: So what you are saying is how you add rows into your Datagrid where the data source is an array, is that correct? In order to do that you need to enumerate through your array and call DataGridView.Rows.Add.